# Screen flashing/flickering on HP laptop

Tags: 22.04, display, screen, 23.04, flicker

I am seeing the built-in display on my HP Elitebook Folio G1 (Intel Core m5-6Y57 with Intel HD Graphics 515) flickering after a fresh install of Ubuntu. It’s worth noting that this doesn’t happen on a live ISO boot. I had Windows 11 and MacOS (hackintosh) installs on this laptop previously but didn’t have this issue.

Things I have tried without success:

1. Ubuntu 22.04 and 23.04
2. xorg and wayland
3. Installed all available updates
4. The [panel self refresh workaround](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Intel_graphics#Screen_flickering)
5. The 6.x, 5.x and 4.x LTS kernels
   Any help will be appry